# Spider returns different results from local machine and Scrapy Cloud(phantomjs+selenium+crawlera)

Tags: selenium, scrapy, phantomjs, scrapinghub

*Hello!*

*Question to one who use scrapinghub, shub-image, selenuim+phantomjs, crawlera.*
*English skill is not good, sorry*

I needed to scrape site which have many JS code. So I use scrapy+selenium. Aslo it should run at Scrapy Cloud.
I've writtеn spider which uses scrapy+selenuim+phantomjs and run it on my local machine. All is ok.
Then I deployed project to Scrapy cloud using shub-image. Deployment is ok. But results of
webdriver.page_source is different. It's ok on local, not ok(HTML with inscription - 403, request 200 http) at cloud.
Then I decided to use crawlera acc. I've added it with:

```
service_args = [
            '--proxy="proxy.crawlera.com:8010"',
'--proxy-type=https',
'--proxy-auth="apikey"',
]
```

for Windows(local)

```
self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'D:\programms\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantomjs.exe',service_args=service_args)
```

for docker instance

```
self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'/usr/bin/phantomjs', service_args=service_args, desired_capabilities=dcap)
```

Again at local all is ok. Cloud not ok.
I've checked cralwera info. It's ok. Requests sends from both(local and cloud).

Note again:
Same proxies(crawlera).
response at windows: 
200 http, html with right code

response at ScrapyCloud(docker instance): 
200 http, html with inscription 403(forbidden)

I dont get what's wrong.
I think it might be differences between phantomjs versions(Windows, Linux).

Any ideas?

Comment: A site is denying access for bots from a well-known scraping service. Do you not see what could be wrong here?

Comment: @Vaviloff , sure I know it. But I am using proxy(crawlera)... As I wrote I use same proxy, same user-agent from both local and scloud, and result is different.

Comment: No experience with selenium and phantomjs but for Splash it's recommended to make a regular (do not use Crawlera) request to Splash and use Crawlera in the Splash request. Maybe a similar logic can be applied for your case.

Comment: Are proxies that you use transparent? Could they be transmitting originating IP of a request?

Comment: Try checking the headers for both [here](https://httpbin.org/headers) and compare them

Comment: @Vaviloff I can see IPs of each request

Comment: @Casper Thanks, it's mb useful